# CallState is never CTCallStateDisconnected?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, phone-call

I am using the `CoreLocation` framework and I am trying to see whether a user is in a phone call or not. I placed my code within a function in `CoreLocation` that is called every second or so, and finds if the user has changed locations. When I run my application, I am able to detect if a call is coming in and when a call is connected, but when the call hangs up, nothing ever prints. Below is my code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {        
    if let calls = currCall.currentCalls as? Set<CTCall> {
        for call in calls {
            if call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected{
                println("Disconnected")
            }
            else if call.callState == CTCallStateConnected{
                println("Connected")
            }
            else if call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming{
                println("Incoming")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The print statement "Connected" and "Incoming" print to the console when the call is incoming and connected but when the call disconnects, "Disconnected" never prints. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure, but you probably only see disconected calls if you hold on to a reference to a `CTCall`. `currCall` is a `CTCallCenter`, right? The call set then is only the [inprogress call set](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCallCenter/currentCalls), and disconected calls are removed from the list immediatly.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about would I go about holding a reference to the `CTCall` then? I see your point and it makes sense

Comment: @user1871869 well, you could add a `callInProgress` property to your class. Then assign connected calls there. Once the call is done, the property for the call state should change to `CTCallStateDisconnected`. Once your logic with that is done, you should probably `nil` that reference.